# Jquery .load element with specific id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
jQuery("#menu li a").click(function(){
            var page_url = jQuery(this).attr("href")
            jQuery(".wide_main").html("<p>loading...</p>");
            jQuery(".wide_main").load( page_url + '#main_content');
});
```

I have this code but it just loads the entire requested page instead of just the #main_content div.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to add space between url and #main_content

```
        jQuery(".wide_main").load( page_url + ' #main_content');
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery example for doing this is:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

It appears it is because you are missing a space after the file and before the container.

http://api.jquery.com/load/